# Why my spi test C code get this result?

Tags: linux, driver, spi

At the bottom is the spi test code (spitest.c) I used, and when running it on my linux kit, I got this result:

```
root@abcd-kit:/system # ./spitest                                     
open device: /dev/spidev0.0
set spi mode: 0
set bits per word: 8
set max speed: 2000000 Hz (2 MHz)
the received data is below:

00 00 00 00 30 30 
30 0A 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 2F 73 
the received data is below:

00 00 00 00 30 30 
30 0A 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 2F 73 

...

dmesg output:

    <7>[ 1254.714088] usif-spi e1100000.usif1: Pushing msg a8085ed0
    <6>[ 1254.714367] SPI XFER  :ae81c700  , Length : 18
    <6>[ 1254.714404]    TX Buf :a6207000 , TX DMA :  (null)
    <6>[ 1254.714425]    RX Buf :92bf5000 , RX DMA :  (null)
    <6>[ 1254.714445]   CS change:0, bits/w :8, delay : 0 us, speed : 2000000 Hz
    <7>[ 1254.714471] TX--->:31 a5 bb 00 00 bb fc 76 80 84 1e 00 5c 29 7d 77
    <7>[ 1254.714491] TX--->:44 b9
    <7>[ 1254.714511] RX--->:00 00 00 00 30 30 30 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    <7>[ 1254.714534] RX--->:2f 73
    <7>[ 1254.714558] usif-spi e1100000.usif1: Msg a8085ed0 completed with status 0
    <7>[ 1255.725936] usif-spi e1100000.usif1: Pushing msg a8085ed0
    <6>[ 1255.726472] SPI XFER  :ae81cc40  , Length : 18
    <6>[ 1255.726604]    TX Buf :a6207000 , TX DMA :  (null)
    <6>[ 1255.726656]    RX Buf :92bf5000 , RX DMA :  (null)
    <6>[ 1255.726706]   CS change:0, bits/w :8, delay : 0 us, speed : 2000000 Hz
    <7>[ 1255.726773] TX--->:31 a5 bb 00 00 bb fc 76 94 29 7d 77 5c 29 7d 77
    <7>[ 1255.726829] TX--->:44 b9
    <7>[ 1255.726875] RX--->:00 00 00 00 30 30 30 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    <7>[ 1255.726925] RX--->:2f 73
```

And the biggest problem is that I cannot get correct result from miso pin (read is wrong, can do write correctly). Whatever I do, e.g. connect miso to ground or 1.8V, it always give this kind of result. The fisrt 5 data are always zero (I think it is because tx buffer has size of 5 and it is half duplex), and then followed random data, even that I used memset() to set rx buffer data to be zero before each spi transfer. And if I stop the program and run it again, the data changed but they are still random.
How could I read correct data from miso pin?
Thanks!

***spitest.c***

```
/*
 * SPI testing utility (using spidev driver)
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007  MontaVista Software, Inc.
 * Copyright (c) 2007  Anton Vorontsov <avorontsov@ru.mvista.com>
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License.
 *
 * Cross-compile with cross-gcc -I/path/to/cross-kernel/include
 */

#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include "spidev.h"

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))

static void pabort(const char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    abort();
}

static const char *device = "/dev/spidev0.0";
static uint8_t mode;
static uint8_t bits = 8;
static uint32_t speed = 2000000;
static uint16_t delay;
#define LENGTH 18

static void transfer(int fd)
{
    int ret, i;
    uint8_t tx[5] = {0x31, 0xa5, 0xbb};
    uint8_t rx[LENGTH] = {0, };
    struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
        .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
        .len = LENGTH,
        .delay_usecs = delay,
        .speed_hz = speed,
        .bits_per_word = bits,  //important, bits = 8 means byte transfer is possible
    };

    memset(rx, 0, LENGTH);

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
    if (ret < 1)
        pabort("can't send spi message\n");

    printf("the received data is below:\n");
    for (ret = 0; ret < LENGTH; ret++) {    //print the received data, by Tom Xue
        if (!(ret % 6))
            puts("");
        printf("%.2X ", rx[ret]);
    }
    puts("");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret = 0;
    int fd;
    unsigned char rd_buf[32];

    fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0)
        pabort("can't open device\n");

    /*
 *      * spi mode
 *           */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set spi mode\n");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE, &mode);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get spi mode\n");

    /*
 *      * bits per word
 *           */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set bits per word\n");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get bits per word\n");

    /*
 *      * max speed hz
 *           */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set max speed hz\n");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get max speed hz\n");

    printf("open device: %s\n", device);
    printf("set spi mode: %d\n", mode);
    printf("set bits per word: %d\n", bits);
    printf("set max speed: %d Hz (%d MHz)\n", speed, speed/1000000);

    while(1){
        transfer(fd);
        //read(fd, rd_buf, 4);
        //printf("rd_buf = %s, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", rd_buf, rd_buf[0], rd_buf[1], rd_buf[2], rd_buf[3]);
        //memset(rd_buf, 0, 10);
        sleep(1);
    }

    close(fd);

    return ret;
}
```

**More:**
My CPU is Intel Sofia-3gr, I guess its spec is not publicly released. I see the Tx data from my oscilloscope, and confirmed that TX is right.
I can also printk the pinmux/pinctrl setting (use ioremap and ioread32), it is also right. I say it right also because that I can see how to set it as SPI from those dts reference files, I just follow them.

**Key:**
I just find that the SPI TX interrupt is pending each time a spi transfer starts, but no SPI RX interrupt pending. Hence the spi driver code will not read the RX data at all. As the reason, I don't know.

Comment: What kind of CPU/SoC are you using? How is your spi device configured in the devicetree (supposed you are on an ARM system)? Are you setting up the correct alternate functions for your the SPI pins and are you really using the correct pins?

Comment: Also, I don't see that your tx data is changing with every transfer - this is due to the TX buffer being too small (5 bytes, not 18 bytes) and not being completely initialized, thus it contains garbage from byte 3 on.

Comment: I update my main post with answers to your questions, please check it. Thanks! @andreas-hofmann